# Compilation error: Contract 'FundMe' object has no attribute 'getEntranceFee'

Tags: solidity

`Contract 'FundMe' object has no attribute 'getEntranceFee'`. I keep getting this error in my compiled code, I have attached the related code

```js
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.6.6;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/vendor/SafeMathChainlink.sol";

contract FundMe {
    using SafeMathChainlink for uint256;
    
    mapping(address => uint256) public addressToAmountFunded;
    address[] public funders;
    address public owner;
    AggregatorV3Interface public priceFeed;

    constructor(address _priceFeed) public{
        priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(_priceFeed);
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function Fund() public payable{
        addressToAmountFunded[msg.sender] = msg.value;
        uint256 minimumUSD = 1 * 10 ** 18;
        require(getConversionRate(msg.value) >= minimumUSD, "You need to spend more ETH");
        funders.push(msg.sender);
    }

    function getVersion() public view returns(uint256){
        
        return priceFeed.version();
    }
    function getDescription() public view returns(string memory){
        
        return priceFeed.description();
    }
    function getPrice() public view returns(uint256){
        
        (,int256 answer,,,) = priceFeed.latestRoundData();
        return uint256(answer * 10000000000);
    }
    function getConversionRate(uint256 ethAmount) public view returns(uint256){
        uint256 ethPrice = getPrice();
        uint256 ethAmountinUSD = (ethPrice*ethAmount) / 10**18;
        return ethAmountinUSD;
    }
    function getEntranceFee() public view returns(uint256){
        uint256 minimumUSD = 1 * 10 ** 18;
        uint256 price = getPrice();
        uint256 precision = 1 * 10 ** 18;
        return (minimumUSD* precision)/ price;
    }
    modifier onlyOwner{
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }
    function Withdraw() payable onlyOwner public{
        msg.sender.transfer(address(this).balance);
        for(uint256 fundersIndex = 0; fundersIndex < funders.length; fundersIndex++){
            address funder = funders[fundersIndex];
            addressToAmountFunded[funder] = 0;
        }
    }//63.729944077200000000
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This error usually occurs when you are unable to access the `ABI File` of the contract or there is something wrong with your `ABI File`.

Possible solutions

1. Re-check the path of ABI File which you used to create the instance.
2. Check if the path of the ABI is correct.
3. Print the output of Instance to check if you've created the web3 instance correctly.